# Bash: How to sort files in a directory by number of lines?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to bash so my knowledge is pretty limited, especially when it comes to writing scripts. Is there any way in which a script can read into the directories it is given and sort the files inside in descending order, from the one with most lines to the one with least?

Comment: Type: `ls -Ssh`

Comment: If your directory contains only not hidden files, then `wc -l directory/* | sort -rn` may be what you need.

Comment: @EdouardThiel If I understood well the sorting criteria is the number of lines, not the size.

Comment: @Renaud indeed, hence `wc -l` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

```
find /some/dir -type f -print0 | wc -l --files0-from=- | sort -n -r
```

Should do what you want

the `find` program scans directory `/some/dir` recursively, outputs the full path for each file it finds (`-type f` means file as in not a directory/socket/etc). the output list uses nul-terminated strings (`-print0`) in order to safely deal with dodgy filenames.

That list of filenames feeds into `wc` (wordcount) which uses (`--files0-from=-`) to expect a nul-terminated filelist as input, and for each file it prints the number of lines (`-l`) in front of the filename.

That list in turn, feeds into `sort` which sorts the list in reverse (`-r`) numeric (`-n`) fashion; and since the linecount is in front of the filenames, that means the longest file (most lines) is on top.